# Laravel: Relationships by hasManyThrough cycle

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I want to made page relations, where i'll have parent page and child page and divide it by levels.
**For example**: page 1 owns page 2, page 2 owns page 3, page 3 owns page 4 (1->2->3->4)

And i have route for each page.

So, i have 3 tables in db:

1. pages
2. routings
3. page_relations

Structure:

1. pages table have all info about page with id.
2. routings have all url path each page by post_id and url.
3. page_relations have all info about page and his page_id and parent_id.

My model for output a pages:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\Routing;
use App\Models\PageRelation;

class Pages extends Model{
    
  use HasFactory;

  public function route(){
    return $this->hasOne(Routing::class , 'post_id');
  }

  public function cycles(){
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
      self::class,
      PageRelation::class,
      'parent_id',
      'id',
      'id',
      'page_id'
    );
  }

  public function writeIds($cycle, &$cycles){
    foreach($cycle->cycles as $tmp ){
        $cycles->push($tmp);
    }
  }

  public function getChildrenAttribute(){
    $cycles = collect();
    $this->writeIds($this, $cycles);
    return $cycles;
  }


}
```

As you can see i used hasManyThrough and function for made recursive record each page to new collect by with(['cycles.cycles.cycles.cycles.cycles.cycles']) on 6 levels.

What i wrote in controller:

```
        public function output_darkside_pages(){
            $relations = PageRelation::get()->pluck('page_id')->toArray();
            $pages = collect();

            foreach( Pages::with('route')->get()->whereNotIn('id',$relations) as $page){
                $page_collection = Pages::query()->with(['cycles.cycles.cycles.cycles.cycles.cycles', 'cycles.route', 'cycles.cycles.route'])->find($page->id);
                $pages->push((object)['page' => $page, 'childs' => ($page_collection ? $page_collection->children : false)]);
            }
            
            return dd($pages);
        }
```

Okay, its maybe its seems good But, when i want to bind route to each page i have add 'cycles.route'  to with array. And if i ant to add 7 levels like in parent/child functionality it's will be view like that:
`$page_collection = Pages::query()->with(['cycles.cycles.cycles.cycles.cycles.cycles', 'cycles.route', 'cycles.cycles.route', 'cycles.cycles.cycles.route', 'cycles.cycles.cycles.cycles.route', 'cycles.cycles.cycles.cycles.cycles.route', 'cycles.cycles.cycles.cycles.cycles.cycles.route'])->find($page->id);`

It's seems like hardcode and i believe that it's should be more beautifull then i have done.

Can you help by give me some advice for figure out that case? I'll really appriciate your help.
Thank you for your attention!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My solution:
It's very interesting but i have done it by iteration as i understand it. So, my code will explain it better:

Controller:

```
 public function output_darkside_pages(){
            $relations = PageRelation::get()->pluck('page_id')->toArray();
            $pages = collect();

            foreach( Pages::with('route')->get()->whereNotIn('id',$relations) as $page){
                $page_collection = Pages::query()->with('cycles')->find($page->id);
                $pages->push((object)['page' => $page, 'childs' => ($page_collection ? $page_collection->children : false)]);
            }
            
            return dd($pages);
        }
```

Model:

```
  public function cycles(){
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
      self::class,
      PageRelation::class,
      'parent_id',
      'id',
      'id',
      'page_id'
    );
  }

  public function writeIds($cycle){
    foreach($cycle->cycles as $tmp ){
      $this->writeIds($tmp);
    }
  }

  public function getChildrenAttribute(){
    $this->writeIds($this);
    return $this->cycles;
  }
```

In the result i have infinite levels of relationships of my pages.